Guidance for asking "Tune my machine learning model" questions
As machine learning (ML) progresses, more and more questions about it are asked on the network. I monitor mainly Stack Overflow and I find an increasing number of questions like these. These type of questions have a working code, but the results are incorrect or inconsistent and the OP would like help tuning their model to have appropriate parameters and thresholds. I'm having difficulty to determine whether this is on-topic for Stack Overflow and if not, if it fits elsewhere on the network.
Issues:

There is no "true" Minimal Reproducible Example, since the training data is missing and ML models heavily depend on that specific data. This is an inherent problem, as the training data is usually (way) too large to be uploaded.
They are not coding questions per se, since their code is working. It's just the parameters or thresholds that need different settings.
It is opinion based in the sense that the "appropriate threshold" is not clearly defined. Perhaps on the actual input data one can define a hard threshold, but otherwise it's up to the OP to decide where to draw the line between accepts and rejects.
It might even be a question about ML theory, in that the OP wants to learn what types of parameters one can set and what rules of thumb there are.
The old Too Localised close reason comes to mind, as the only person capable of determining whether a specific new threshold or parameter set suffices is the OP. Future readers won't get much help either, as their parameters and thresholds need to be set differently for their problem.

All in all I'm fairly sure these type of questions do not belong on Stack Overflow, but I'm not familiar enough with other sites on the network to determine whether they'd be on-topic anywhere else. Possible sites to point the OP to would be Cross Validated,  Data Science, Artificial Intelligence, or Code Review amongst others.
What to do with these kind of "Tune my ML model"-questions?
Related links on meta SE and meta SO:

Seeking Stack Exchange site for machine learning questions?
Where to ask basic questions about machine learning?
Guidance for asking machine learning questions
Standard for machine learning questions
Dealing with the influx of "help me tweak my AI model" questions

Especially this last post suggests closing these questions on Stack Overflow as Too Broad (now Needs Focus), which I tend to agree with. Are they on-topic elsewhere though?

I think an important 'side' question here is 'can i give enough information for someone else to answer this?"

@JourneymanGeek to me it seems that the answer within SO would be "No", as the data is simply too large to be provided. If the data could be provided outside of SO I'm still inclined to say "no", because the model can always be improved or extended to new data, incorporate more parameters etc. The only person capable of determining whether a model is "good enough" is the OP. Whether there are sites on the network that are more lenient with such suggestion-questions that SO is unclear to me though.

@Adriaan: Even if allowed on some site or other, the chance of attracting an answer may be slim. They're not a very enticing kind of question.


What to do with these kind of "Tune my ML model"-questions?

Post on SO if it's a coding issue, or Data Science SE if it's an AI issue. MWEs can be provided using public datasets, and appropriate thresholds can be chosen so that they aren't too far away from SOTA, or least significantly better than random or majority baseline. If about AI theory, then can post on Cross Validated,  Data Science or Artificial Intelligence.

So these questions should be directed to [datascience.se]? They aren't true programming issues, in the sense that the code is running, they need different parameters/thresholds. And if the OP understands what they are doing, it shouldn't be a problem with the theory.

@Adriaan yes, these questions should be directed to Data Science.

Note that implementation - i.e. code questions - are explictly off-topic for AI.SE.

Discussion about the topicality on DataScience.SE: Are "improve my ML model" questions on-topic?

N.B. Cross Validated isn't only for theoretical machine-learning questions - e.g. the ones I've linked in my answer are rather practical.

@Scortchi-ReinstateMonica Thanks, yes, since OP wrote "It might even be a question about ML theory, in that the OP wants to learn what types of parameters one can set and what rules of thumb there are." I used that definition of ML theory, but that definition includes "generic versions" (as you wrote) that are not necessarily about theory. E.g., https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/240305/12359;
https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/177905/12359; https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/180548/12359;
https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/205932/12359; https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/184290/12359

Yes - you're familiar with the site of course, but I wouldn't want someone who wasn't to get the wrong idea.

It can make sense to find, or write, more generic versions of such questions to use as duplicate targets; see e.g.
the discussion at What's the best way to answer "my neural network doesn't work, please fix" questions?, & the resulting posts at What should I do when my neural network doesn't learn? & What should I do when my neural network doesn't generalize well?
Lacking the input data, even if there's any interest in trying to answer them, they tend to devolve into a series of guesses as to what might help & to not be especially useful to other users besides the O.P.

I agree here, which is why I mentioned the old "Too Localised" close reason. Too bad we cannot close posts as cross-network dupes, otherwise those two general targets on stats you linked would come in handy. I think I'll stick with closing them as Needs Focus on SO and not mention the rest of the network in a comment.
